# GWT Real world projects

Tags: gwt, web

Besides the list of real world projects powered by GWT from below

1. http://gwtgallery.appspot.com/
2. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/examples/#real-world-projects
3. http://www.ongwt.com (last update: 30 JUNE 2011)
4. http://www.gwtsite.com/whos-using-gwt/

Where else I can find list of projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking GWT gains momentum and the quantity of such projects in the net grows exponentially.

There're great projects using GWT:

- [Odnoklassniki](http://odnoklassniki.ru). Russian social network with 25.3 million active users
- [Google Moderator](http://google.com/moderator). Service that  allows  to vote on user-submitted questions, suggestions and ideas and uses crowdsourcing to rank
- [Google Orkut](http://orkut.com). Social network with over 33 million active users. Has tight integration with other Google services (GTalk, Google Video, ect.)
- [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com). Service that supports discussion groups and threaded conversations
- [Google AdWords](http://adwords.google.com). Program enables to create advertisements and to promote products under cost-per-click model
- [Google AdSense](http://google.com/adsense). Program delivers AdWords ads to particular websites
- [Google Document Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer). Service on the Google Docs platform allowing to view documents with different formats directly in browser
- [Google Web Fonts](http://google.com/webfonts). Directory of web fonts allowing the use of hundreds of previously non-safe fonts on websites

Surely there's some other projects in Google using GWT. For example maybe geo part of [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/) and [Google Offers](https://google.com/offers/home).

But in addition to strong successful GWT projects it should mention the sensational project [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com) and [Google Buzz](http://buzz.google.com) have been discontinued. First one was an online tool for real-time communication and collaboration. And Buzz was social networking tool that was integrated into Gmail.

And variety of small GWT projects:

- [Finbudget](http://finbudget.com)
- [3D Port](http://3d-port.com)
- [KDice](http://kdice.com)
- [GPokr](http://gpokr.com)
- [Random Homepage](http://therandomhomepage.com)
- [Traffic Info](http://gtraffic.info)

See also these links that are given me by google:

[Sites built GWT](http://www.quora.com/What-web-applications-use-Google-Web-Toolkit-%28GWT%29)

[Using GWT for production apps](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/a2991a0000efab40you?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compilation of real world projects:

- http://gwtreferencelist.appspot.com/

(I found it referenced from [Google is using GWT – and you?](http://blog.oio.de/2011/12/14/google-is-using-gwt-and-you/))

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13838117)

Comment: But to be precise, that would then not really be an answer to the question "Where else I can find list of projects?" - he didn't ask "What other projects are there?"